# How to purposely send mail to spam folder?

Tags: email, outlook, email-spam, spam-prevention

Most people want to find a way to get the email they send out of the spam folder but I'm wondering if it's possible to force an email to be marked as spam. I do have a legitimate purpose for this, but I won't be getting into that.

I'm using a PERL script that sets headers then appends a body and sends the message off using `sendmail` without `SMTP`.

I did an analysis of several emails marked as spam vs legitimate emails. What I thought would trigger a spam response would be setting various common headers:

```
X-Spam-Score: 6.5
X-Spam-Level: ******
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Status: Yes
```

This doesn't cause a message to go into the spam folder.

Since I use outlook, I also tried setting `X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 9` which didn't work.

I tried various other headers as well with no luck. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think it really depends on the spam filter that the destination's email client is using. Usually some sort of word frequency analysis, etc. I don't think this is possible in a general way. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering. You could fill the email with common spam words, but I don't imagine that's what you want to do.

Comment: If your spam filter supports GTUBE testing, get the sample message from http://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/

Answer (score 0):

SpamAssassin publishes a test message for this purpose.

http://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/